# Can't properly send HTML email with attached file via smtplib in python

Tags: python, html-email, email-attachments

I try to send email which contains text, html version of body and attached file.
I use [standart python example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html) with additional code:

```
img = MIMEImage(some_image_file)
img.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="file.jpg"')
msg.attach(text_body)
msg.attach(html_body)
msg.attach(img)
```

Gmail show my email well, however yandex.com' email client shows only attached picture without html or text body of the letter.

If I change order like that:

```
msg.attach(img)
msg.attach(html_body)
```

Yandex shows only html body of my letter, and do not show attachment!

Is there any additional headers I need to add in order to show my email correctly (html/txt body AND attached file) in any email clients?

Answer (score 0):

After some research of email headers sent from normal email client, I found solution:

```
body = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
....
body.attach(text_body)
body.attach(html_body)
msg.attach(body)
msg.attach(img)
```